# UITableview data is changing when I scroll

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

I have made this protocol in my cell class

```
protocol CellDelegate: AnyObject{
func plusButton(tag: Int) 
func minusButton(tag: Int)   
}

class CartTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {    
@IBOutlet weak var plusButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var minusButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var itemsCountLabel: UILabel!

weak var delegate: CellDelegate?
var count = 0
var totalAmount = 0.0
var modelPrice:Double = 0.0
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    itemsCountLabel.text = String(count)
    
}

@IBAction func addButton(_ sender: Any) {
    
    delegate?.plusButton(tag: (sender as AnyObject).tag)
    count += 1
    totalAmount = modelPrice * Double(count)
    itemsCountLabel.text = String(count)
    
}

@IBAction func minusButton(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.minusButton(tag: (sender as AnyObject).tag)
    if count > 0{
        count -= 1
        totalAmount = modelPrice * Double(count)
        it  emsCountLabel.text = String(count)
        print(totalAmount)
    }
}
```

}

this is the code I have placed in my cellForRowat method in my viewcontroller

```
cell.delegate = self
cell.plusButton.tag = indexPath.row
```

and added this extension

```
extension ViewController: CellDelegate{
func plusbutton(tag: Int)
func minusButton(tag:Int)}
```

When I tap on plus button my countLabel is incremented and vise versa. The issue is when I scroll the tableView my values are shuffled(not same). What is the reason and how to solve this.

Comment: Cells are reused. Make sure that all UI elements are set to a defined state in `cellForRow`. And `(sender as AnyObject)` is pretty *unswifty*. Change the `sender` parameter to the real type `UIButton`. And is this the real code? `cellDelegate` vs `CellDelegate` and twice `func plusButton(tag: Int)` doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code you modify the value of count in the cell. Do you modify it in your model in the cell delegate aka controller ? I so you need to keep coherency in your cell by either updating the label in the cell or either reload the cell in the cell delegate.